# How to perform webdriver backed selenium in selenium 3?

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-rc, browser-automation, selenium3

How to perform webdriver backed selenium in selenium 3 ?

Selenium 3 has recently removed the feature called 'webdriver backed selenium'

I have to perform mouseover, type operations like this, which is no more supported in Selenium 3.

```
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.google.com");
selenium.openWindow("http://www.google.com", "google");
selenium.mouseOver(anElement);
```

I have tried with moveToElement method , But it doesn't executes in my site .
Thats why I was using webdriver backed selenium in Selenium 2 (WebDriver).

What work around I have to do to get this in Selenium 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you probably know, WebDriverBackedSelenium provides Selenium 1.x (Selenium RC) compatible interfaces but it's 100% implemented using WebDriver.

There are many downsides to use it, for example - WebDriverBackedSelenium is significantly slower than using WebDriver APIs directly. But let's stick with the original question :)

With the [release of Selenium 3.0](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2016/10/04/selenium-3-is-coming/), it was decided to delete the original Selenium Core implementation. For the one that have used the old RC interfaces, Selenium team have provided an alternative implementation that’s backed by WebDriver which is the same as WebDriverBackedSelenium that has been available as part of Selenium 2 since its release.

This implementation is the [Selenium Leg Rc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-leg-rc). In order to use it, just include the dependency in your project, for example, using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-leg-rc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And now you will be able to work as you worked until now, with Selenium 3.0 with WebDriverBackedSelenium.